# Close recommendation question with link only answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

In my opinion the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158759/sql-query-cheat-sheet looks a lot like the very reason that the "recommendation/off-site resource" close reason exists. The fact that several links in the answers are dead serves to illustrate the point of the close reason.

It does have a few stars and some upvoted answers, but shouldn't it be closed despite that?

**Update: the question is now closed, so mission accomplished. Thank you.**

Comment: Maybe even deleted... At least one of the [answers links](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6158786/1324033) has already died

Comment: @Sayse That was my assessment too, but I wanted to get some second opinions (but primarily to have it closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be closed because it is no longer on-topic based our current standards.

Of course, it being closed does not mean that the question and its answers itself are bad or not useful. So there is nothing wrong with having it closed but keeping it around so people interested in it can still access it and use the information there if they want to.